# SoundCloud-Python AttributeError: 'ResourceList' object has no attribute 'collection'

Tags: python, api, python-requests, soundcloud

I am following the guidelines here https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python (built around Python requests), and I am trying to list all the tracks in my soundcloud account (https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks), with their correspoding metrics such as plays, likes, etc.

```
# create client object with app and user credentials
client = soundcloud.Client(client_id=client_id,
                           client_secret=client_secret,
                           username=username,
                           password=password)

# print authenticated user's username
name        =  client.get('/me').username
track_count =  client.get('/me').track_count
tracks      =  client.get('/tracks')
print name, track_count
```

I can get the values in the print statement, but if I try to do this (taken from the example)

```
for track in tracks.collection:
    print track.title
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'ResourceList' object has no attribute 'collection'
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
for track in tracks:
    print track.title
```

You could also try to define tracks as follows:

```
tracks      =  client.get('/tracks.json')
```